# Xamarin Android preserve method from Linking

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-fusedlocation

I'm using Google Fused Location API in my Xamarin app. It all works fine in Debug mode.
However, when I set it in Release Mode, with Linking enabled, it doesn't work on the device. I'm pretty sure that it is because of the linking.
How do I preserve the methods I'm using from the Fused Location API (like "RequestLocationUpdates")?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot link a single method from an assembly.

If you didn't do so already, did you consider setting your linking conditions to `Link SDK Assemblies` in your `Project Options`? This will avoid that the packages you depend on are being optimised to reduce the application size. SDK assemblies on the other hand, such as the ones which comes with `Xamarin.Android`, will be optimised. Read more [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#Linker_Behavior).

Otherwise, you can use [link skipping](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#linkskip) which essentially allows you to define explicitly which SDKs you do not want to be optimised.